# How to remove quoted strings, containing exact pattern, from a file

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have the below content in a file.txt:

```
"prom-oa-eui-slrcloud-plt4.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","auth-oa-eui-slrcloud-plt4.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","dex-oa-eui-slrcloud-plt4.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","dashboard-oa-eui-slrcloud-plt4.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","argocd-oa-eui-slrcloud-plt4.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","alert-oa-eui-slrcloud-plt4.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","tntcloudid.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","tntcloudid-df.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","tntcloudid-superset.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","tntcloudid-orchflow.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","tntcloudid-dmgr.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","tntcloudid-ps.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","vanity-tntcloud.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","vanity-tntcloud-df.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","vanity-tntcloud-superset.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","vanity-tntcloud-orchflow.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","vanity-tntcloud-dmgr.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","vanity-tntcloud-ps.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","tntcloud1id.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","tntcloud1id-df.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","tntcloud1id-superset.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","tntcloud1id-orchflow.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","tntcloud1id-dmgr.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","tntcloud1id-ps.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","vanity-tntcloud1.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","vanity-tntcloud1-df.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","vanity-tntcloud1-superset.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","vanity-tntcloud1-orchflow.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","vanity-tntcloud1-dmgr.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","vanity-tntcloud1-ps.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","tntcloud2id.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","tntcloud2id-df.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","tntcloud2id-superset.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","tntcloud2id-orchflow.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","tntcloud2id-dmgr.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","tntcloud2id-ps.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","vanity-tntcloud2.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","vanity-tntcloud2-df.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","vanity-tntcloud2-superset.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","vanity-tntcloud2-orchflow.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","vanity-tntcloud2-dmgr.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","vanity-tntcloud2-ps.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com"
```

I want to delete all strings with the "tntcloudid" and "vanity-tntcloud" occurrences, only if I have those pattern in entry.

I tried the below code:

```
sed -e "s/tntcloudid//g; s/vanity-tntcloud//g" file.txt
```

But it's remove only the "tntcloudid" and "vanity-tntcloud" and not the remaining string from the line, like ".test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","-df.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com" etc...

As I have others strings like vanity-tntcloud1, vanity-tntcloud2 etc... those strings are impacted and I don't want remove those part of strings, but only my pattern ("tntcloudid" and "vanity-tntcloud" only)

I tried with the below code but the result it's the same:

```
sed -e "s/\<tntcloudid\>//g; s/\<vanity-tntcloud\>//g"
```

How can I remove only the lines matching with the "tntcloudid" and "vanity-tntcloud" pattern without impacting the others string for which the content is "vanity-tntcloud1" ... "vanity-tntcloud2" etc... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your own explanation, you want to replace the entire surrounding token which contains this text, rather than only the text itself. You need to articulate a regular expression which matches everything that should be replaced.

With GNU sed:

```
TENANTID=tntcloudid
VANITY=vanity-tntcloud

sed -E 's/"[^"]*\<'"$TENANTID"'\>[^"]*"(,|$)//g; s/"[^"]*\<'"$VANITY"'\>[^"]*"(,|$)//g' file.txt
```

Comment: It's working fine, many thanks, but the result is to have several commas like :
"prom-oa-eui-slrcloud-plt4.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","auth-oa-eui-slrcloud-plt4.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","dex-oa-eui-slrcloud-plt4.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","dashboard-oa-eui-slrcloud-plt4.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","argocd-oa-eui-slrcloud-plt4.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","alert-oa-eui-slrcloud-plt4.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com",,,,,,,,,,,,,"tntcloud1id.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com","tntcloud1id-df.test1.devops.oa.iqvia.com"

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working very fine, but last question, how updating this command if my patterns (tntcloudid and vanity-tntcloud) are variables (e.g : $TENANTID and $VANITY), I'm asking because I'm afraid to have some issue with simple and double quotes, but many thanks for your help

Comment: I just tried to replace the pattern by variables and the return is : sed: -e expression #1, char 39: Invalid preceding regular expression
Here's my command :
sed -E 's/"[^"]*\<${TENANTID}\>[^"]*"(,|$)//g; s/"[^"]*\<${VANITY}\>[^"]*"(,|$)//g' file.txt

Comment: @bessey Read the updated answer. Note that if the contents of variables contain special characters (such as `/`, `*`, `[`, etc.) the `sed` command will fail.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working as expected. You unblocked me to achieve my script, thanks.